# One to One Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand how to show that $Ker T=\{0\}$...

$$T:M_n (R)\rightarrow M_n (R)$$
$$T(A)=A+2A^T$$

Show that $T$ is one to one.

thank you all!

Comment: Perhaps you should break the problem into two parts: what is required for the diagonal entries of $T(A)$ to be zero, and what is required for the off-diagonal entries to be zero.  Combining those requirements should convince you that $A=0$, if $T(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to invert $T$ explicitly. Let $B=A+2A^T$. Then
$$B+B^T = 3(A+A^T),\quad B-B^T = A^T-A$$
and therefore
$$A = \frac{1}{6}( B+B^T - 3(B-B^T)) = \frac{1}{3} (2B^T-B)$$